# How to Prove a Matrix is Not a Vector Matroid Over $\mathbb{R}$: Fano Plane Example

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, matroids

[[image: <span class=]$\therefore$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc9f0.png)

Above is point-line incidence geometry for the Fano Plane.

In other words, this matroid $M$ has a ground set $E(M)=\{ a, b, c, d, e, f, g\}$ and a collection of bases $\mathcal{B}(M)=\{X\subseteq E|X\neq \{a, e, b\},  X\neq\{b, g, c\}, X\neq \{c, f, a\}, X\neq \{e, d, c\}, X\neq \{f, d, b\}, X\neq \{a, d, g\}, X\neq \{e, g, f\}, \text{ and } |X|=3\}$.

> $\textbf{Question:}$ This matroid $M$ is not representable as a vector matroid over the real numbers. I want to prove that it is not representable over the real numbers, but I am not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated!

---

This is what I was have/was thinking so far for a proof...

Let $A$ be a matrix with column labels $a, b, c, d, f, g, e$  (i.e. 7 total).

As the rank of matrix is $3$ and $\{a, b, c\} \in  \mathcal{B}(M)$, the first three columns can be simplified to this: 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

As $\{c, d, f\}\in \mathcal{B}(M)$, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I did delete and edit the question, because $\mathcal{B}(M)$ was incorrect. Sorry about that for those who looked at the question before these edits.

Comment: [This proof](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/representing-the-fano-matroid/) using only [Ceva's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) and [Menelaus's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) is pretty slick.

Comment: I feel like there is a way to do this by looking at matrix without so much geometry. The only reason I am saying this is because I want to generalize this to other matroids which cannot be represented over $\mathbb{R}$ as vector matroids. I could possibly be wrong on that note. I do appreciate your help though and I will look into those theorems!